# What's the preferred way to put music in a java applet?

Tags: java, music

Is there an easy way to put music in a java applet? Preferably streaming so that it doesn't need to be preloaded.

Comment: As this isn't game development specific, you might get a better response at http://www.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [something like this](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5406593), though as the author said he didn't stream so it stuttered. You'd want to preload a certain amount of the sound before feeding it to the Line.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly what I'm looking for, but I guess there is no other easy way to do this. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.jsresources.org/) may help you, it contains a lot of examples of how to use the Java sound API (loading, playing, streaming, recording...).